# Unable to add features in QGIS 2.4.0

Tags: qgis, shapefile, proj

QGIS beginner problem. I can no longer create features with "Add Feature" in QGIS.

The info triangle message is

> "Transform error caught: forward transform of (0.000000, 0.000000)
>   PROJ.4: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +to +proj=utm +zone=11
>   +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs Error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits"

Using Windows 7, 64 and QGIS 2.4.0

Project CRS: WGS84 / UTM Zone 11N, EPSG:32611, OTF enabled, filter blank.

Answer (score 2):

"Add feature" came back!

A green X on endpoint of a line on a different layer than I wanted to use and that was left over from a previous session (and that I could not turn off, even after restarts and reboots) became a start point once things suddenly began to work. Still a mystery.